# Fabricjs : item locked but group selection possible

Tags: fabricjs

Basically I'm trying to reproduce this behavior for locking/unlocking item in fabricjs:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/undtb1v4kxqcbi8/ScreenFlow-lock.mp4?dl=0

=> I want to be able to lock an item, but still be able to clic and drag a selection from it, but still being able to select it (but not moving/scaling,etc).

I can lock an item and be able to start a drag selection from it:
https://jsfiddle.net/og09g5ex/

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
left: 100,
top: 100,
fill: 'red',
width: 150,
height: 150,
transparentCorners: false,
evented:false,
selectable:false});
```

But then I can't select it because I use "evented=false".

Does anyone has an idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can't select it because you have used selectable:false, remove that and then it will allow you to select the object but not move/scale.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my point. If it's selectable, I can't drag+select. Take a look at the video behind the dropbox link. My message is probably unclear without watching it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible but it is not easy. There [is a `findTarget` in the `canvas.class.js` file](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/7ff1063c07429fd8b33809437de4cdca5db9d762/src/canvas.class.js#L1082) that you will need to modify so that when you are clicking on the object you select it but when you are clicking then dragging it does not select it. naively fabric does not have this concept and modifying this function is the only way to get it. Hope that helps!